# Windows 10 UWP app async/await usage on long running task

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

have a Windows 10 UWP app targeting .Net core. I am still grasping the async/await process but I am starting to understand it and use it more. The question is, if I have a long running task that may mostly be sitting idle, for example an http client waiting and listening that I want to have in the background while the user continues to use the app, is async/await still a good use for this type of case or is this one that is better to actually run in another thread?

Thanks!

Comment: You should do some testing to set what is best in your use case. There is no code to indicate how this will be used, and that would be necessary to make a suggestion.

Comment: There's no general rule on when to use async or thread. This would all depends on the situation, application type etc. Even with the code sample and requirements you will get many different answers. You should try it for yourself check if this fits your needs and application design.

Comment: Thank you for the input so far. I dont have any code written yet or I would share. Was just looking for input before I get started down a path only to hear after that I should have done it differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think async/await will not be a good idea for these type of scenarios. App has to wait till the operation is completed which is not good user experience. You can just create a background task for that and trigger the task according to your conditions.